# How to avoid a system generated e-mail going into spam?

Tags: php, email, email-spam, spam-prevention

I've written code for sending an e-mail using php. I don't want to go that mail into spam. How can I avoid going that mail into spam?

```
<?php

$EmailTo = "name@example.com";
$Subject = "Enquiry from xxxx Website";
$name = $_REQUEST["name"];
$Body = $_REQUEST["body"];
$Subject = $_REQUEST["subject"];
$emailfrom = $_REQUEST["email"];
$phone = $_REQUEST["phone"];
$comments = $_REQUEST["comments"];
$todayis = date("l, j F Y, g:ia (T)") ;

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers .= "Organization: Sender Organization\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\r\n";

// Prepare email body text
$Body = "Here is the information collected from your online enquiry form. It was submitted by:\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $todayis;
$Body .= "\n\n";

$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";

$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $emailfrom;
$Body .= "\n";

$Body .= "Phone: ";
$Body .= $phone;
$Body .= "\n";

$Body .= "Comments: ";
$Body .= $comments;
$Body .= "\n";


// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$emailfrom>");

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's up to the spam filter marking it as spam, but make sure your DNS MX headers are configured properly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your server is not on a blacklist. If you are on a dynamic IP, most likely you are. Check at http://www.spamhaus.org/

Answer (score 0):

Mail classification is done at the receiving end, not the sending end. So whatever you do, you can't allways avoid being classifed as spam.

BTW: If you manage to find the 100% "I AM NOT SPAM" receipe, let me know. I have this exciting bsiness oportunity with an unclaimed fortune in Nigeria.

So: Fix th problem where it lies: At the receiving side. Make sure your host's IP address is whitelisted, just as you sender address (or sender/receiver tuple depending on your filer

Answer (score 0):

Like David said, it depends on the spam filters. Every email server/email provider has its own set of rules, but generally there are several common errors to avoid:

> 1. Using spammy phrases, like “Click here!” or “Once in a lifetime
>      opportunity!” Going crazy with exclamation points!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
> 2. USING ALL CAPS, WHICH IS LIKE SCREAMING AT THE TOP OF YOUR LUNGS VIA
>      EMAIL (especially in the subject line)
> 3. Coloring fonts bright red or green
> 4. Coding sloppy HTML, usually from converting a Microsoft Word file to
>      HTML
> 5. Creating an HTML email that’s nothing but one big image, with little
>      or no text (since spam filters can’t read images, they assume you’re
>      a spammer that’s trying to trick them) Using the word “test” in the
>      subject line (agencies run into this when sending drafts to clients
>      for approval)
> 6. Sending a test to multiple recipients within the same company (that
>      company’s email firewall can only assume it’s a spam attack)
> 7. Designing HTML email in Word and exporting the code to HTML (That
>      code is sloppy, and spam filters hate it.)

You can refer to MailChimp's "[How spam filter think"](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-spam-filters-think/) for a good read.

Answer (score 0):

I know you're sending plain text, but if you ever decide to send something in html, **make sure not to use old, deprecated html tags**. I got spam-listed once for having `<font>` tags and the like, which were being inserted by NicEdit.

Just a nugget for everyone out there.